# Receive results from frequency term in other language properly

Tags: r, tm

I try to run term frequency into another language

```
 df <- data.frame(freetext = c("Εδώ και αρκετό καιρό που συνεχίζουν","και τώρα που έγιναν"))

library(tm)

docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$freetext))
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
head(d, 3)
```

However the results I see in console are:

```
word freq
\xea\xe1\xe9                                                         <ea><e1><e9>    2
\xf0\xef\xf5                                                         <f0><ef><f5>    2
\xe1\xf1\xea\xe5\xf4\xfc                                 <e1><f1><ea><e5><f4><fc>    1
```

How can I fix the encoding?

Comment update:

```
tibble::tibble(words = names(v), freq=v)
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  words                                       freq
  <chr>                                      <dbl>
1 "\xea\xe1\xe9"                                 2
2 "\xf0\xef\xf5"                                 2
3 "\xe1\xf1\xea\xe5\xf4\xfc"                     1
4 "\xe5\xe4\xfe"                                 1
5 "\xea\xe1\xe9\xf1\xfc"                         1
6 "\xf3\xf5\xed\xe5\xf7\xdf\xe6\xef\xf5\xed"     1
7 "\xdd\xe3\xe9\xed\xe1\xed"                     1
8 "\xf4\xfe\xf1\xe1"                             1
```

Comment: what does `tibble::tibble(words = names(v), freq=v)` return?

Comment: @phiver I update the question with the output

Comment: interesting. Check `Encoding(df$freetext)` and if this is anything other than UTF-8, try setting it to UTF-8 like this: `Encoding(df$freetext) <- "UTF-8"`